# not going on a get to know meeting (recruiter)

Tags: career-development, software-development, careers, career-switch

Recently a recruiter contacted me via linkedin. Telling me "their team had many novelties, and were looking for a software developer in say C#" and was suggesting a meeting of *"getting to know each other" type, with a perspective for possible future cooperation(employment).*

Since I am currently not much interesting in changing my position, at least for 6 months, I kindly rejected offer to meet.

Even though **I feel** the suggestion was kind of to get to know each other, so that maybe they could offer something even in the future, if I don't want this current offer.

But since I don't plan changes at least for next 6 months I saw no point in meeting, and told her kindly I'd get back to her once I make my mind more about changes in my career.

Was it wrong from my side? And maybe I should anyway had gone to meeting of "get to know type"? Because I would kind of not lose anything from meeting? Can it be seen as a bad tone from me?

Comment: Recruiters live by building relationships, but this kind of random outreach is little more than spam unless you have reason to believe they have clients who are of particular interest to you.   Feel free to either ignore it, or request that they demonstrate some actual relevance, including that they've taken time to understand what would be relevant to you.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I posted as "guest" initially but will add info that this was not a standalone recruiter rather a recruiter working within an organization, that was interested to hire devs for that organization.

Comment: Then you should decide if that organization is interesting to you or not. If it is, pursue or politely postpone. Any serious internal recruiter has to understand a well phrased expression of "not at present but perhaps later" though of course their specific needs can change too.  And if the organization is of no interest at all, no response at all is necessary - anyone with a professional profile gets unending spam about obviously irrelevant possibilities.

Comment: Is this a known recruiter /headhunter  working for a well known agency if so going might be in your interest - though the tone of this contact "many novelties" suggests its not.

Answer (score 4):

> Recently a recruiter contacted me via linkedin.

This is (generally) called "recruiter spam". They can send hundreds or thousands of messages at once to linkedin contacts that match particular criteria as an easy way of getting people "on their books", so to speak. (Occasionally they're well-targeted and asking you about a particular position which fits your skillset, but that's the exception.)

The only thing I'd advise doing with these messages is ignoring them. I wouldn't even have replied.

If you're looking for a role, then you can search for / register with appropriate recruiters at that time. There's zero point in replying to a random recruiter that wants a "getting to know you" meeting when you're not even looking for a job.

Answer (score 1):

In my area, it was common for recruiters to buy a possible recruit lunch at a decent restaurant.   One place where I worked, it was the steakhouse across the street.  I always enjoyed getting a free dinner and making a business contact.   If they're willing to take you to good place to eat, go for it.  It can't hurt.